# Nest Extension Methods for MVC HtmlHelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to nest a set of extension methods for my MVC controllers i want to be able to call in the following pattern

```
@Html.NestedName().CustomLabelFor(m => m.Field)
```

I have noticed that TwitterBootstrapMVC follows this pattern but i have been unsuccessful at replicated it.. Could someone show me an example of how i would structure my extension method class?

Currently i have my top level class as below

```
    public static class BootstrapHtmlHelper
{
    public static BootStrap Bootstrap(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return new BootStrap(html);
    }
}
```

Nested in the Bootstrap class i have the following method

```
        public static MvcHtmlString CustomLabelFor <TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string placeholder)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Obviously this cannot be static anymore but how do i replace what would have been "this" so that my method an still function? Obviously TModel and TProperty are still required but i am unsure how to bring them into scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.  Let's break this down into two pieces:

1. You need a static class to house your extension method (`BootstrapHtmlHelper`).
2. You need a non-static class to house your instance method (`BootStrap`)

So, you just need to change your second method to:

```
public MvcHtmlString CustomLabelFor<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string placeholder)
```

Also, you'll need to modify `BootStrap` to store the model type parameter passed in the extension method.  So declare `BootStrap` as `BootStrap<TModel>` and pass that in when creating a new `BootStrap` (i.e. `new BootStrap<TModel>(html)`).

Now you should be able to invoke it as you desire:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().CustomLabelFor(m => m.Field)
```

(You had `@Html.NestedName()` but obviously `NestedName` should be `Bootstrap`, since that's the name of your extension method, right?)

Comment: Yes this resolves my issue but stops me passing in the helper correctly, i will update my question.

Comment: I did, with where i am now :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you.. Actually i had to do one more thing as i didn't like the idea of passing the Html value in to the enclosed methods i did this by storing this in the Bootstrap class as a property which was references from within the methods. Really appreciate the help! I get really confused with <Type> tags on classes on methods. What is the name for this topic?

Comment: It's called ["generics"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) (or parameterized types, or templates). It's strange at first, but as you can see, it's very powerful and can allow you to write some pretty awesome API methods. :)